# How to Open a XAML Window from another Project?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I added a new WPF project to the solution and was just wondering how trigger the other project/XAML Window to start when needed. I added all projects references required. I understand that switching XAMLs is easy within one project, for example change StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml". But a XAML from another project?!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the same manner. Key here is in relative uri type:

```
this.StartupUri = new System.Uri("/someOtherAssembly;component/NewMainWindow.xaml, UriKind.Relative);
```